# App is stuck installing on my iPhone, how do I fix it?

Tags: iphone

I started updating my Twitter app, but then I lost the internet connection and when I went home I couldn't get it to resume the installation. It stops just past the half way mark with the lines on the icon. It has been like this for months.

How can I unstick the stuck application install?

Comment: FYI, I've been experiencing these sorts of problems consistently on my iPhone 6 Plus & iPad Air 2 for several months -- i.e., probably correlated with my transition to iOS 9. I've reported the problem to Apple via iTunes email support (1/16/2016), phone support (1/16/2016), and Bug Reporter (just now). The phone support specialist (front-line call handler, not a member of any engineering team) confirmed that he has personally experienced this problem and continues to, and believes it's associated with iOS 9. He indicated that he had contacted an applicable engineering team based on his own exp

Answer (score 1):

You mentioned this device was upgraded from iOS 9. In my experience an iPhone that has been upgraded from previous OS that has not had a full restore on it in years is prone to reliability issues like this.

I typically do a restore at least one time per year (I experiment a lot and "cruft up" my phone).

Its a pain however its probably time for a full restore...  The phone will run like new afterwords.

---

*Note: Back up all data before you preform this action, otherwise all data will be lost.*

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem with the Pages app, actually a couple of times, my solution the second time was simply updating to the iOS 9 Public Beta, so **just updating to iOS 9 should fix your issue.**

Here's an alternative way to solve this, just for good measure. It was how I solved the issue the first time:

1. Open iTunes your Mac or other computer.

   2. Connect your iPhone.
   3. Click on the icon of your iPhone in the top left.
   4. Choose "Back Up Now".
   5. Upon completion of the backup, click Apps under "On My Device" on the left.
   6. Search for the app that is giving you trouble, in your case Twitter.
   7. Click "Delete" to the right of the problematic app.
   8. Click "Sync" in the bottom right of the iTunes window.
   9. After your iPhone syncs, go to the App Store on your iPhone on reinstall the app.

Answer (score -1):

Settings - General - Storage and Icloud Usage - Manage Storage ( On the top ) - Click On App - Then Uninstall

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  We like answers to be more than just a single line.  Ideally, you want to explain why your answer is *right."  It also helps to provide links, citations, and/or screen shots.  Please review our help section [How to Answer](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) on writing good answers to questions